# MapQuest API - Insight from users

Tags: php, json, mapquest

I need to be able to extract a list of states the route passes through. Is there any functionality within the api that will provide this information?

e.g. A route that crosses 6 states from start point to end point. Get list of states. Preferably in order of crossing.

I'm not looking for code help. I've searched through the api and google with no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function in the MapQuest directions api that returns a list of states for a route. But if the stateBoundaryDisplay parameter is set to true, the response will contain details like, "Crossing into Nebraska", in the maneuver text. The manuevers will be in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks for the info.
Extending on this question, is there a way to get the milage per state? stateBoundary to stateBoundary?

My app needs to pull the state names and also determine distance traveled per state.

Comment: Nope, there is no distance for each state in the route result. I don't know a simple method to grab that data either. You could probably have a file of state shape points on your side and compare that to the route shape points and find the border crossings to use the points between to calculate the distance. But that seems pretty wonky.

Comment: I was thinking I'd define states via stateBoundary. And if possible get a lat/long for that point. Then get the lat/long for the next state boundary. This would be the inner state route. run a route request for it to get total distance.

Comment: Just a matter of whether or not I can get a lat/long for each boundary and build the inner state route.

Comment: If you have those state boundaries, you can definitely route through each state to find the distance. If you only need the distance, you could use the route matrix which is simpler and only returns time and distance.